# apply test suite to implementations of a interface

Tags: java, interface, junit

I have a interface for which there exists several implementations.
I'm setting up a test suite for the interface. Now I want to run all test classes from the suite for each of the concrete implementors.

to clarify, I have a setup like

- TestSpam.java
- TestEgg.java
- TestBacon.java

which are all testing diffrent aspects of my interface IBreakfast, and I'm going to have them organised in a suite called say TestBreakfast. And I want all the diffrent tests to be run for specific implementation specified somehow, preferably once and on/to the suite.

At the testcase level I think I could use parametrise to run for all implementations, but doesn't look like that extends to suites. And also when using parameterise it looks like I would have to hardcode the implementations which feels horribly backwards.

Any idea on how to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

In this situation, I've repeatedly settled into a pattern like the following:

- Create an abstract class which tests the expected functionality for the interface.

  - This class should declare an abstract factory method which returns an instance of the interface.
  - All of your tests should use the instance returned by the factory method.
- Create one or more classes (one for each implementation) which extend this abstract class.

  - Implement the factory method by returning the appropriate concrete class.
  - Use this concrete test class to also test implementation-specific functionality.

Comment: Thanks, but how would you go about extending that to test suites? I really want to avoid subclass all test classes.

Comment: To clarify: You're trying to programmatically create a parent `TestSuite` containing `TestSuite` instances for each the interface's implementations. Are you wanting to find the implementations completely through reflection, or are you wanting to provide a list of classnames/class instances to the constructor for your `TestSuite`?

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear, updated the original question with a clarification. So no, that's not really what I'm after here. reflection or not doesn't really matter, but I assume passing a instance will be easier

Comment: @keis: I apologize, but I've got a post-full of content about this in my head, but I haven't yet had a moment to get it out. I will probably try to get it in tonight when I get a spare moment.

Comment: hey ryan, would love to hear your suggestion.